# accessing keyvault secrets from azure functions fails

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Due to some limitations, I am not able to test the azure function first locally and then deploy it.
So, we have followed the approach of working around, with the use of pipelines.
I have a repository in Azure git, where I have a folder (azure-functions) containing **init**.py, functions.json and requirement.txt.

I create a new function from the pipeline using the following script inside the pipeline yaml.

```
func init LocalFunctionProj --python
cd LocalFunctionProj
func new --name TimeTrigger --template "Timer trigger" --schedule "0 */5 * * * *"
```

Now the above command creates a new **init**.py , functions.json and the requirement.txt.
I copy the contents of the files from azure-functions(in my repo) to these files created above.

Now, I have the init.py where I try to access the dummy keyvault value, but end up facing with the module not found error.

init.py

```
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import azure.keyvault.secrets as kv_secrets
import azure.identity as az_identity
#from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
#from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    
    KVUri = f"XXXXXX"
    credential = az_identity.DefaultAzureCredential()
    logging.info('credential info is %s',credential)
    #client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)

    client = az_identity.SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)
    password = client.get_secret('TestSecret').value
    logging.info('Secret value is %s', password)


    logging.info('Hello!! Good day!')
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

The requirement.txt has the following entries :

```
azure-functions
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.28.0
azure-identity==1.13.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
```

I deploy the function using the pipeline itself, and it is successful.
The time triggered response shows the following:

```
Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.keyvault'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 380, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 48, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 44, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 132, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "/home/site/wwwroot/TimeTrigger/__init__.py", line 5, in <module> import azure.keyvault.secrets as kv_secrets
```

Comment: Try adding -azure-keyvault in requirements.txt and rerun your function?

Comment: Or pip install azure-keyvault==4.1.0 if you want to use earlier version, Refer here- https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault/#

Comment: Also, May I know which pipeline are you using? github or Devops?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I am using DevOps

Comment: Any luck by adding  azure-keyvault  in the requirements.txt? Meanwhile I am testing it in my environment

Comment: Thank you very much :) And nope, I added the azure-keyvault in requirements.txt and it was not successful

Comment: Can you try running pip install -r requirements.txt with requirements.txt file set to azure-functions
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.28.0
azure-identity==1.13.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
azure-keyvault I was able to resolve the issue locally by running pip install -r requirements.txt first and then running func host start. Now, I am performing the deployment with Devops pipeline.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test it locally, but since I am running the pipeline against ```ubuntu-latest```, I am trying to do a  ```func start``` after pip install. I get the following : ```Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5198 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.21.1.20667

The listener for function 'Functions.TimeTrigger' was unable to start.
The listener for function 'Functions.TimeTrigger' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage: Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor. ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running `pip install -r requirements.txt` and then ran `func host start` and the Function ran but it gave an error in your init.py code.

**My requirements.txt:-**

```
azure-functions
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.28.0
azure-identity==1.13.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
azure-keyvault
```

As **azure identity class does not include SecretClient, It gave an error.** I replaced your code -

```py
client = az_identity.SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)
```

with the code below and it worked, I also replaced `DefaultAzureCredentials` with **`AzureCliCredentials`** like below:-

```py
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import azure.keyvault.secrets as kv_secrets
import azure.identity as az_identity

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    
    KVUri = f"https://keyvaultvalley.vault.azure.net/"
    credential = az_identity.AzureCliCredential()

    # Use SecretClient from azure.keyvault.secrets
    client = kv_secrets.SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)
    password = client.get_secret('TestSecret').value
    logging.info('Secret value is %s', password)

    logging.info('Hello!! Good day!')
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**Local:-**

[image]

But ***AzureCliCredentials won't work in Azure Functions Deployment via Devops as Function app cannot authenticate with your Azure account and key vault via CLI as the interactive authentication is not supported in Function app***. One option is to create Azure Service principal and assign it a role to Key vault and deploy the code in function app ***another way is to authenticate the existing code with ManagedIdentityCredentials with Function app.***

***init.py with ManagedIdentityCredentials:-***

```py
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import azure.keyvault.secrets as kv_secrets
import azure.identity as az_identity
az_identity.ManagedIdentityCredential()
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    
    KVUri = f"https://keyvaultvalley.vault.azure.net/"
    credential = az_identity.ManagedIdentityCredential()

    # Use SecretClient from azure.keyvault.secrets
    client = kv_secrets.SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)
    password = client.get_secret('TestSecret').value
    logging.info('Secret value is %s', password)

    logging.info('Hello!! Good day!')
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

Enable **`System assigned managed identity for your Function app`** like below:-

[image]

Add **`Key vault Contributor role to Above Function app managed identity`** on **Key vault** and **`assign access policy to access Secret on Key vault.`**

[image]

[image]

Now, I uploaded my Function source code file to Azure repository and ran the Pipeline in Devops like below:-

**My Azure repository:-**

[image]

**My function.json:-**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

**host.json:-**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**requirements.txt:-**

```
azure-functions
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.28.0
azure-identity==1.13.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
azure-keyvault
```

*Select new Pipeline your Azure repository with functions code and use existing template like below:-*

[image]

Select your subscription correctly and your Function app when asked for prompt after selection the option above.

**Yaml pipeline script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxx4-c61cd03e7111'

  
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc210'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Devops pipeline ran successfully:-**

[image]

**Output Azure Function app:-**

[image]