# Incorrect response in Azure Functions Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function which connects to the keyvault to access the secret and prints it out. Its on a HTTP trigger, and is as follows:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential



def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
        KVUri = f"https://XXXXX.azure.net/"
        credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
        logging.info('credential info is %s',credential)
        #client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)

        client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)
        password = client.get_secret('TestSecret').value
        logging.info('Secret value is %s', password)
        return func.HttpResponse("Function executed successfully", status_code=200)
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

When I test this function, I get a the following error:

```
Message: The user, group or application 'appid=XX;oid=XX;iss=XXX' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'XXXXXX;location=westeurope'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287
Inner error: {
    "code": "AccessDenied"
}
```

The secret is present in the keyvault. However, since this is a failure, I expect the log to show the failure. But the log ends with : [image: Response]

Should it not be a failure here? [image: Response2]

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly received similar error as you have got :

[image]

Then, I have used below below workaround which worked for me:

Here you need create a [app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) like below:

[image]

Secondly, you need to add the client id of app registration as below in Key vault:

Click on  **`Access Policies`**, Then Click on **`Create`**:

[image]

Give what **`permissions`** you want to do:

[image]

Then search the **`clientid`** (of the app registration) and click on it and then create it:

[image]

Then, I have used below code and it worked for me(integrate this code into your function app):

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient


tenant_id1 = '72f988bf-'
client_id1 = '74230c16-'
client_secret1 = '4Ei8Q~EaEqf0~8jWbD0W5V'
key_vault_name1 = 'rith99'
secretname1 = 'rithwik'
credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id1,
    client_id=client_id1,
    client_secret=client_secret1
)
keyvault_url1 = f"https://{key_vault_name1}.vault.azure.net"
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=keyvault_url1, credential=credential)
retrieved_secretvalue = secret_client.get_secret(secretname1)
print("Secret value:", retrieved_secretvalue.value)
```

You will get tenant id, [client secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-credentials) from Certificayes & secrets section and object id from App registrations managed identity.

**`Output:`**

[image]

If you want to do by managed identity of function app you can refer this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76873358/accessing-keyvault-secrets-from-azure-functions-fails/76874470#76874470).

Comment: Thank you.. But why wrong status codes are seen?

Comment: No, its not wrong code, any authentication error code comes with 403, But Glad it helped

Comment: But for me, although its 403, it shows the success flag.. that is unclear

Comment: If you get any response back from the server it gives you success,  and 403 shows success in Invocation tab, any other error other than that shows as failed and we are handling this as a response of function app ( by using return) so we are getting success

Comment: so even though its a failed authentication, it is correct to show success in the invocation tab? not the failed error code?

Comment: Yes, that is what I know, and the same thing you have observerd in this scenario